# Removing a line with a certain element from a text file

Tags: java

I am trying to remove all lines with `0.0` from a text file.

This is what it outputs:

```
0037823478362839 0.0
0236530128715607 3.88
0425603748320896 36.09
0659644925904600 13.58
0823485731970306 0.0
0836430488858603 46.959999999999994
```

This is what i want it to output

```
0236530128715607 3.88
0425603748320896 36.09
0659644925904600 13.58
0836430488858603 46.959999999999994
```

Code:

```
// Collects the billing information and outputs them to a user defined .txt file
public void getBill() {
   try {
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputFile);
        Passenger[] p = getAllPassengers();
        for(Passenger a : p){
            printStream.print(a.getCardNumaber() + " ");
            printStream.println(a.getBill());
        }
        printStream.close();
   } catch(Exception e){
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of `Passenger`, especially the return type of `getBill()`.

Comment: For starters: It's called Java, not JAVA, it's not an acronym.

Comment: It appears that you just have to test the value of a.getBill(). If it equals 0 then you don't print the corresponding line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a `if` to check if the `bill` amount is `0.0` and if it is not, print it, otherwise, don't print it. If the `getBill()` returns a String, then you need to parse that String to a double and then check it in the `if`.

```
for(Passenger a : p){
    if(a.getBill() != 0.0){ // the if to check the value of bill
        printStream.print(a.getCardNumaber() + " ");
        printStream.println(a.getBill());
    }
}

for(Passenger a : p){
    double dBill = Double.parseDouble(a.getBill()); // in case getBill() returns a String
    if(dBill != 0.0){ // the if to check the value of bill
        printStream.print(a.getCardNumaber() + " ");
        printStream.println(a.getBill());
    }
}
```