# java Removing a line with a certain element from text file

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to remove all lines with 0.0 as its printing to a text file.

This is what it outputs,

> 4177516040935072 14.94
>
> 4270931484327447 7.54
>
> 4308546496189733 7.1
>
> 4421407386000242 0.0
>
> 4436391685645089 0.0

This is what I want it to output

> 4177516040935072 14.94
>
> 4270931484327447 7.54
>
> 4308546496189733 7.1

This is my code:

```
Collection<Passenger> c = passengers.values();
        Iterator<Passenger> itr = c.iterator();
 

        try {
                
            while (itr.hasNext()) { 
        
                //System.out.println(itr.next().getBillAmount());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOutput,true));
            writer.append(itr.next().toString());
             writer.newLine();
             writer.close();
            }
            
            
            
            
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19704426/2024761) which I answered just a while back, for a very similar question.

Comment: Hey R.J, I had a look at that answer and I tried it, but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Did you try both the options?! The one where you parse the String to a double and then have a `if`?

Comment: "doesn't work for me" doesn't work for us. Could you be at least so kind to tell us **how** "it" (what exactly?) did not work?

Comment: yeah I tried both options, so basically the data gets sent to the Treemap, so if I return anything from getBill(), it's 0.0 as it's already been stored to memory (Treemap). So theres no data to do anything with

Answer (score 1):

Split the value and check if any of the tokens contain `0.0`.  Also declare the `BufferedWriter` outside of the loop and also close it outside of the loop.  Also use the `write()` method on `BufferedWriter` instead of `append()`.

```
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOutput,true));
        while (itr.hasNext()) { 

            List<String> values = Arrays.asList(itr.next().toString().split(" "));

            if(!values.contains("0.0")){
                writer.write(itr.next().toString());
                writer.newLine();
            }
         }
         writer.close();
```

Comment: Hi thanks,

it creates the text file, no errors etc but it doesn't seem to write anything.

Comment: Try moving the line that closes the writer outside of the loop.  See updates in the answer.

Comment: yeah I moved it around, it's still showing the occasional 0 and then it ends with a Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1113)
 at java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1160)
 at Q1.outputBillAmountFor(Q1.java:105)
 at Q1.main(Q1.java:38)

Comment: @Javanoob33 did you use write instead of append?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer :

```
    if (!String.Contains(" 0.0") {
          System.Out.println(...);
    }
```

with the reason that if we use endsWith(); maybe we have a space at the end of the string

Comment: Can't seem to get this one to work. What am i adding where String is, I've tried the itr.next().toString().Contains( etc but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 while (itr.hasNext()) { 
        if (!itr.next().toString().contains(" 0.0"))
        {
          //System.out.println(itr.next().getBillAmount());
          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOutput,true));
          writer.append(itr.next().toString());
          writer.newLine();
          writer.close();
        }
 }
```

Comment: What about `123123120.0` ?

Comment: this one doesnt work, as it just provides me with all values as 0.0's

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.endsWith()` method

```
if (!String.endsWith(" 0.0") {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: True, I didn't think about that. Fixed with a space.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work, but it would be best if you have access to the source code for the Passenger class. If the passenger class has 2 fields which both get written to the String result in `toString`, then it would be best to access the field whose value to want to check via its getter.

I have also re-arranged your code a bit so that you are not closing and re-opening your BufferedWriter every line

Example:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOutput,true));

while (itr.hasNext()) { 
    Passenger p = itr.next();
    if (p.getSomeField() != 0.0) {
      writer.append(p.toString());
      writer.newLine();
    }
}

writer.close();
```

Comment: Hi, this one doesnt seem to work. the file gets created, but no data gets written to the file. correct file name etc

Comment: Can you confirm that the lines `writer.append(...)` and `writer.newLine()` are being reached?

Comment: Hi, yeah they work. it prints to command etc but I keep getting an error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1113)
 at java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1160)
 at Q1.outputBillAmountFor(Q1.java:106)
 at Q1.main(Q1.java:38)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
for(String line : lines)
{
    for(String word : line.split(" "))
    {
        if(word).equals("0.0")
        {
            lines.remove(i);
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

You can use simply

```
if(line.contains("0.0"))
{
    lines.remove(i);
}
```

if it can be anywhere in the line. Or

```
if(line.endsWith("0.0"))
{
    lines.remove(i);
}
```

if it's always on the end of the line.